# DOSY-NMR: How to calculate the volume of the molecule from the diffusion coefficient?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

DOSY-NMR allows for the determination of the diffusion coefficient of the analyte molecule. How do I calculate the volume/radius of the molecule from the diffusion coefficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try and use the Stokes-Einstein equation for the diffusion coefficient $$D=\frac{k_\mathrm{B}T}{\zeta}$$ where the friction term is $$\zeta = 6\pi\eta r$$ and $k_\mathrm{B}$ is the Boltzmann constant, $\eta$ the solvent viscosity $(1\ \mathrm{cP} = 10^{-3}\ \mathrm{kg~m^{-1}~s^{-1}} = 10^{-3}\ \mathrm{Pa~s})$ and *r* the molecule's radius . You only have one number in diffusion constant so you can only get radius or volume assuming the molecule is a sphere.

The model assumes that the molecules are larger than the solvent molecules, i.e. solvent is effectively continuous not molecular. There are slightly different expressions for the friction, 4 instead of 6 for example depending on whether 'slip' or 'stick' limits are assumed.

Comment: Are there other ways to calculate the volume without assuming the molecules to be a sphere. Can I calculate the diffusion constants using e.g. MM or DFT?

Comment: @ketbra  What exactly are you after? Don't you know what substance you are measureing?

Comment: @Karl I know the substance but whant to show wheather its a monomer/dimer/tetramer and want to argue with the size of the molecule.

Comment: If you only have one measurement then you can only assume a sphere, you do not have enough information to assume a prolate or oblate spheroid. You should be able to distinguish monomer etc just from the diffusion coef as the molecules probably coil up or cluster in some way . You can certainly get size & shape from calculation. If you could measure *rotational* diffusion, say by fluorescence anisotropy, then this gives a better idea of shape.

Comment: @ketbra You can surely differentiate betwen monomers, dimers and trimers spectroscopically. After that the diffusion cofficients are distinctive.

Comment: @Karl That's a funny comment. Sure the diffusion coefficients will be different. The question is not how to distinguish them, but how to _identify_ them: giving only the single _measured diffusion constant_, deciding on whether its a monomer, dimer or other oligomer. E.g. the diffusion constant is 50 is it a monomer or an oligomer?

Comment: @porphyrin "If you only have one measurement then you can only assume a sphere" OK, then I will just perform the NMR measurement twice thanks ; )
"You should be able to distinguish monomer etc just from the diffusion coef" OK, but _how exactly_?

Comment: DOSY is diffusion ordered *spectroscopy*. What is that stuff that you cannot identify monomer, dimer and oligomer out of the spectrum? Or is this a hypothetical question? Are you measuring a pure substance? Mixture?

Comment: @ketbra, ha-ha: very good comment :) As to monomer/dimer etc presumably you know roughly the size of molecule you study, thus compare  diffusion coeff with literature values to others of similar sizes, then look at you data to see how much bigger/smaller  your values are. At least this will give you a start. Also your data should show different types of molecules dispersed in value, perhaps grouped also and that should help identify monomer , dimer etc.

Comment: @porphyrin I see : ) I just thought that there maybe is a program similar to Mobcal for collision cross section to predict diffusion coefficient but maybe I will just write my own then ; )